# Transferring MDF/LDF files to target server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Background:

I have a medium-sized database (900GB) that needs to be copied onto another server (driven via code, not scheduled). Currently we take a backup (to .bak), move it to a staging server, and restore it to the target server. The target server does not have enough space to hold the backup file, and the restored instance simultaneously, thus the staging server. These transfers (backup to staging, restore from staging) happen over SMB2. The staging server needs to go away due to business requirements, however. It is worth mentioning the target server will be taken offline (and used offline) after the transfer, so I'm not sure the mirroring or replication options are valid.

I have identified two options -- one is to backup the database to the primary server, and open up firewall rules/smb to serve the backup file to the target server over SMB. ("RESTORE FROM \x.x.x.x\blah\db.bak"). Security isn't a fan, though.

The ideal solution (and one that could easily be implemented in every other database I've worked with), is to quiesce the database and transfer the datafiles (in the case of ms-sql, mdf and ldf files). However, upon research I see there is no such functionality available out of the box. I know I can take the database offline to copy the mdf/ldf safely, but that's not an acceptable solution (database must remain online).

I have read LOTS of posts and Microsoft documentation regarding VSS / shadow copy, but I have also read lots of conflicting information about the reliability of using VSS/sqlwriter to copy the mdf/ldf file to the target server, and simply re-attaching the database.

I am looking for documentation or advice (or even backup software that can be programmatically driven via an API) to accomplish this goal of transferring the database without requiring a secondary holding place. Currently I'm researching how to drive this copying process with Powershell, using VSS(vssadmin/vshadow from sdk), but I'm not confident in what I'm reading, and it's not even clear to me if VSS/sqlwriter is a supportable method to copying online LDF/MDF files. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe Log Shipping would be an option here?

Comment: How complex is the database?  If is just a few huge tables or many tables and complex business logic?  I ask because if it is just a few huge tables, you could leverage BCP which is probably the fastest way to export/import data.  We use it all the time.

Comment: Vastly, unknowably complex. Probably 2-300 tables. Lots of stored procedures, views, complex business logic, triggers, and so on.

Comment: Why can't you buy an external SSD  (Intel 1.6TB) for a couple of hundred dollars, backup to it, and then attach it to the target and restore from the SSD. Explain to the hardware people that no production will be run off the SSD and it wont leave the data center.

Comment: RE: log-shipping -- I don't think that's an option. The target server comes back from offline wiped clean, so would have to re-establish the entire db anyways.

Comment: SSD idea is not terrible. I can probably do encrypted backup to ssd on target over SMB, and then restore from the SSD. (Attaching SSD to primary is a physical impossibility due to mission requirements).

Comment: Since you said OFF LINE, i'd just save it to fileshare so both servers can see it. Security would be fine with this i think, since you can restrict it to the two servers.

Comment: RE: scsimon, that's the current process -- that staging server is the fileshare. It's going away, though, due to other requirements. :-/

Comment: Ah, I've just found out the Target machines don't run Enterprise, which is a pre-requisite for TDE :-/